# Dynamic Property Creation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Let me try and illustrate an example.

I have a database table called `Grades`.  Here is what it looks like currently.

```
|    Id    |         Grade       |
      1         Exceeds Standards
      2         Meets Standards
      3         Below Standards
```

Now I have code that looks like this:

```
var myTestingExample = db.AnotherTable.Where(x => myList.Contains(x.FirstForeignKeyId))
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.SecondForeignKey.Value, x.SecondTable.Name})
    .Select(
        x =>
            new MyViewModelClass()
            {
                Id = x.Key.Value,
                Name = x.Key.Name,
                CountName = x.Count(),
                CountBelowStandards = x.Count(y => y.GradingSystemId.Value == 3),
                CountMeetsStandards = x.Count(y => y.GradingSystemId.Value == 2),
                CountExceedsStandards = x.Count(y => y.GradingSystemId.Value == 1)
            }).ToList();
```

Now my concern is if the user wants to create another `Grade`.. then I would have to manually add another property to `MyViewModelClass` and then have to add another line of code to the above code to get the count..  I really would want this to be dynamic so I don't have to add properties to my view model class.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: You can have a key-value pair? Which stores grade as key and value as its description?

Comment: @FaizanRabbani you mean a dictionary? Can you display an example?

Comment: Yes, I mean a dictionary.

Comment: oh this is a cool question and scenario. Let's solve it together. I need more information. How can the user edit the db-table `Grade` ? What db-technology are you using? Entity? Linq2SQL ? can you post a snippet of `MyViewModelClass` ? is `MyViewModelClass` represented as a db-table also?

Comment: @GTown-Coder did the answer below help?

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want involves introducing inheritance. See below

```
public class SomeViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<IGrade> grades;

    public SomeViewModel()
    {
        Grades = new ObservableCollection<IGrade>()
        {
            new Grade(1, "BelowStandards"), 
            new Grade(2, "MeetsStandards"), 
            new Grade(3, "AboveStandards") 
        };
    }

    // Add new grade here.
    public void AddGrade(string name)
    {
        if (Grades == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("can't be null here");

        Grades.Add(new Grade(Greads.Count + 1, name));
    }

    public ObservableCollection<IGrade> Grades 
    {
        get { return grades; }
        set { SetField(ref grades, value, "Grades"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, string propertyName)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
}

public interface IGrade : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    int Id { get; }
    string Name { get; }
}

public class Grade : IGrade 
{
    public Grade(int id, string name)
    {
        Id = id; 
        Name = name;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, string propertyName)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    private int id;
    public int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { SetField(ref id, value, "Id"); }
    }

    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { SetField(ref name, value, "Name"); }
    }
}
```

Then in your XAML, you bind to the relevent `Grade` properties. So when the user adds a new Grade, it gets displayed. Happy days.

I have not tested this code, but it should work, or at least give you the right way to go about doing what you want.

If the user wants to change the name of a grade a run time, this should also work with the above code.